# How to fix this error singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport FASLE in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to create webview based android application.

In my application i play the videos . I saw the error in logcat  `singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE`.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Which version of Android it occurs.

Comment: I am trying in android 2.2 (device samsung galaxy s gt I9003)

Comment: Android 2.2 and below had a lot problems with selectors -webkit functionality.Android 2.2 device with default webkit browser then this will work, in any other case you are out of luck.